# Изменение классов по кликам

Tags: javascript, html

Нужен javascript который будет делать следующее:
по клику на кнопку `.step-1 .btn-no` (Шаг-1), должен добавляться класс `.hidden` к первому `tr` в таблице. Тоже самое и с остальными - там где нажимают "нет", скрывается соответствующий `tr` в таблице.
Если на всех шагах нажали "нет", то во всех `tr` надо убрать класс `hidden` т.е. показать все `tr`.

```css
.step-1,.step-2,.step-3,.step-4 {
  font-size: 1.4rem;
}
.btn-yes,.btn-no {
  display: inline;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #000;
}
.btn-yes:hover {
  color: green;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed green;
}
.btn-no:hover {
  color: red;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed red;
}

table {
  margin-top: 30px;
  font-size:1.2rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="step-1">
  Шаг 1 -
  <div class="btn-yes"><span>да</span></div>
  <div class="btn-no"><span>нет</span></div>
</div>
<div class="step-2">
  Шаг 2 -
  <div class="btn-yes"><span>да</span></div>
  <div class="btn-no"><span>нет</span></div>
</div>
<div class="step-3">
  Шаг 3 -
  <div class="btn-yes"><span>да</span></div>
  <div class="btn-no"><span>нет</span></div>
</div>
<div class="step-4">
  Шаг 4 -
  <div class="btn-yes"><span>да</span></div>
  <div class="btn-no"><span>нет</span></div>
</div>


<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr><td>text 1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>text 2</td></tr>
  <tr><td>text 3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>text 4</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здравствуйте!

Обернуть .step-1,.step-2,.step-3,.step-4 родительским блоком и тогда:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".btn-no, .btn-yes").click(function(){
        var $this =  $(this),
            index = $this.parent().index(),
            $rows = $("table tr");

        if ($this.hasClass("btn-no")) {
            $rows.eq(index).addClass("hidden");
        } else {
            $rows.eq(index).removeClass("hidden");
        }

        if ($rows.length === $("table tr.hidden").length){
            $rows.removeClass("hidden");
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, подскажитте пожалуйста -если таблица и блок с да\нет, находятся в разных секциях, как быть?

Comment: Таблица и блок с да\нет могут находится в разных секциях (естественно, нужно обращать внимание на селектор таблицы, чтобы выбирать именно ту, которая нам нужна). Единственное условие это обернуть это самый блок с да\нет в родительский блок (т.е. блоки .step-* должны быть помещены в конкретный блок, который будет являться родителем только для них). Это необходимо для того чтобы сопоставлять индексы tr и индексы блоков .step-*

Comment: дело в том, что верстка немного другая http://prntscr.com/8ongbs  
общий блок получается `.owl-wrapper`, подскажите пожалуйста какие изменения нужно внести в скрипт?

Comment: Тогда заменить строку `index = $this.parent().index(),` на `index = $this.parents(".owl-item").index(),`

Comment: Огромное спасибо :)